# WooCommerce small description under image

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to add a small description under the product image and title in the (woo commerce) shop page, maybe 4 -5 bullet points or something. I found some code on here to put in function.php but crashed the site. (Maybe it was too old or something?)any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add action `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title` to functions.php like below and product short description will be displayed under title in the shop page.

```
function add_product_text_under_title() {

    echo '<p>'.the_excerpt().'</p>';

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_product_text_under_title', 9 );
```